# Rewrite pattern in Jboss

Tags: java, spring, jboss, axis

I have a Eclipse project with a webproject and a SOAP service created with Axis. It generates only one war. My server is Jboss 7.1

My url for webroject and webservice are working fine:

*http://server/webproject/index.jsp*

*http://server/webproject/services/services?wsdl*

I want to modify only webservice url context to be diferent like this:
*http://server/ws/services?wsdl*

The url web must continue working on *http://server/webproject/index.jsp*

I have tried to modify standalone.xml to redirect it so if I use
*http://server/ws/services?wsdl* it will be redirected to:
*http://server/webproject/services/services?wsdl*

This is the code I have tried but it doesnt work fine, I cant replace "*ws*" for "*webproject/services*". It only replace *"webproject"*

```
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <rewrite pattern="^/ws(.*)$" substitution="/webproject/services/$1" flags="L"/>
            </virtual-server>
```

Comment: did you tru: <rewrite pattern="^ws(.*)$" substitution="webproject/services/$1" flags="L"/>

Comment: Yes, not working